# Import CSV to Microsoft Server Management Studio v. 18.9.1 yields title's with a questionmark

Tags: sql, ssms

when converting a csv file into a database accessable through Microsoft Server Management Studio, the names are ended with a questionmark for only some of the names.

E.g. the titlestring "Løn" is from the csv file translated into "Løn?". The csv file is in UTF8 BOM format, so I was hoping this wouldn't be an issue.

Does someone know what could be the root cause?

[image]

Comment: Most likely you missed to change the encoding from the default (ANSI?) to UTF8 on the file import property configuration. Also check if the individual columns data type is `DT_WSTR`.

Comment: This must be due to your row separator is not recognized by the encoding used to read the csv file